# How does the following interaction with Swords to Plowshares and Death's Shadow work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Death's Shadow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeath%27s%5d%2b%5bShadow%5d) is a `13/13` that gets `-X/-X` where `X` is your life total.

If one I control is exiled by [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d), then last known information is used to tell us how much life should be gained, but this happens before the life gain from the Swords, right?  I would not necessarily gain 13 life, but rather the current size of Death's Shadow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what happens, so barring any other side effects*, you'll always end up with 13 life.

*: e.g. a card which doubles any life gained, like [Boon Reflection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoon%20Reflection%5d) (thanks @MichaelSnook)

Comment: You hypothetical life gain doubling card actually exists: Boon Reflection

Comment: also killing one death shadow (with swords) will always kill all the deaths you control?

Comment: @NeilMeyer barring any other effects, yes